# just installed and can't access admin, need to set up 2 factor authentication but no email is sent

Tags: magento2, two-factor-authentication

I've just in stalled magento 2.4.0 and trying to log into the admin area.

it returns a message telling me I have to set up two factor authentication and that I've been set an email.

***You need to configure Two-Factor Authorization in order to proceed to your store's admin area***

***An E-mail was sent to you with further instructions***

I've checked every email I have and there is no email.

this is on a live server

Answer (score 1):

> **Please disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth module**

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:c
```

> **OR**

> Into **Magento_root/app/etc/config.php** find **Magento_TwoFactorAuth** and put 1 to 0 like this then save the file and run php bin/magento s:up
> command.

```
'Magento_TwoFactorAuth' => 0,
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: is there no way of doing it without using command line? I just want to log into the backend for the first time

Comment: Please check and update me.