# Magento 2 - How to solve Two-Factor Authorization Error in Admin Area

Tags: admin, error, stores, two-factor-authentication

After putting my Id and Password in Magento 2.4.1 then I found this error at admin login, seems like it is related to two step Authentication, Please tell me the steps to follow to resolve this error. 
 I am attaching the screenshot of this error -
[image]

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328594/82670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Please disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth module**

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:c
```

> **OR**

> Into **Magento_root/app/etc/config.php** find **Magento_TwoFactorAuth** and put 1 to 0 like this then save the file and run php bin/magento s:up
> command.

```
'Magento_TwoFactorAuth' => 0,
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 1):

please run below command in terminal Magento root path :

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento cache:flush
```